# PyQt5 тип Iterable[QStandardItem]

Tags: python, qt, рекурсия, pyqt5, treeview

Сразу напишу просьбу, объясните пожалуйста что за тип `Iterable[QStandardItem]`? "Google" вообще молчит на эту тему...

Или же помогите впихнуть готовое дерево (неважно список строк или какой любой другой тип)  в `QStandardItemModel` и в итоге в `QTreView`.
Или же помогите пожалуйста написать рекурсивную функцию для заполнения `QTreView` из списка созданного чтением из базы данных, или же сразу из базы данных.

Я пытаюсь создать дерево `QTreView` при помощи `QStandardItemModel`
и никак не могу разобраться с типами аргументов в методе `appendRows()` из `QStandardItemModel` и `QStandardItem`.

```
subnodelist.appendRow(QStandardItem("s1"))
subnodelist.appendRow(QStandardItem("s2"))
subnodelist.appendRow(QStandardItem("s3"))

nodeList.appendRows(subnodelist)
```

Компилятор говрит:

> nodeList.appendRows(subnodelist)
>    TypeError: appendRows(self, Iterable[QStandardItem]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStandardItem'

Я радуюсь что метод принимает список из переменных типа `QStandardItem` и посылаю ему следующее:

```
self.treeStruct = [QStandardItem("root1"), 
[QStandardItem("root1"), QStandardItem("child1_1"),
[QStandardItem("child1_1"),QStandardItem("subChild1_1_1"), QStandardItem("subChild1_1_2")], 
QStandardItem("child1_2"), QStandardItem("child1_3")],
QStandardItem("root2"), [QStandardItem("root2"), QStandardItem("child2_1"), QStandardItem("child2_2"), QStandardItem("child2_3")],
QStandardItem("root3"), [QStandardItem("root3"), QStandardItem("child3_1"), QStandardItem("child3_2"), QStandardItem("child3_3")]]
```

Чтобы вы не ломали глаза, структура списка примерно такая:

```
root1--- child1_1 --- subchild1_1_1
                  --- subchild1_1_2
     --- child1_2
     --- child1_3

root2--- child2_1
     --- child2_2
     --- child2_3

root3--- child3_1
     --- child3_2
     --- child3_3
```

Единственное "но", я добавил в каждый подсписок имя родителя первым элементом (то есть, с нулевым индексом). Чтобы удобно было определять родителя (может это лишнее...).

Но тогда он ругается этим:

> nodeList.appendRows(self.treeStruct)
>    TypeError: index 1 has type 'list' but 'QStandardItem' is expected

Comment: Посмотрите статью PyQt5 Treeview  http://littlecaptain.net/pyqt5-treeview.html

Comment: Спасибо, но в этом примере вообще нету ветвлений дерева. А мне нужно дерево схожее с файловой структурой, хранящееся в базе данных

Comment: Я нашел эту статью, попробую использовать его технологии, он правда писал на  C++. Если кому понадобится: https://habr.com/post/172187/

Comment: Может этот пост вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391050/how-to-remove-row-from-qtreeview-using-qabstractitemmodel

Answer (score 0):

`Iterable[QStandardItem]` - это не тип, но требование, чтобы параметр метода `appendRows()` был (например) список объектов типа `QStandardItem`.

У вас это не *список* (таких объектов), но *просто объект* (по-видимому типа `QStandardItemModel`).

Comment: Да в первом случае это так, но во втором же нет. На второй случай я нашел ответ экспериментально. Этот метод принимает только одномерный список. А в моем случае `self.treeStruct` - многомерный, поэтому он и не принимал его.